# Transformar dataframe de formato longo para wide

Tags: r, tidyverse

Tenho um `dataframe` no formato longo e gostaria de transformá-lo para o formato wide para exportar para o Excel. Estou usando a função `pivot_wider` do pacote `tidyr`, mas os valores estão saindo dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu `dput`:

```
structure(list(data = structure(c(14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 
14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 
14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 
14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14761, 14761, 14761), class = "Date"), 
    estado = c("AC", "AL", "AM", "AP", "BA", "CE", "DF", "ES", 
    "GO", "MA", "MG", "MS", "MT", "PA", "PB", "PE", "PI", "PR", 
    "RJ", "RN", "RO", "RR", "RS", "SC", "SE", "SP", "TO", "AC", 
    "AL", "AM"), `Empréstimo com Consignação em Folha` = c(500066.99, 
    819964.53, 1108300.2, 843603.42, 3236825.05, 2069187.92, 
    4828194.9, 1407455.53, 2600518.79, 1622407.06, 5812565.54, 
    1427935.96, 1381850.15, 2139968.3, 1238364.17, 2671315.9, 
    1001832.72, 3468577.46, 11622283.08, 1586040.82, 796443.91, 
    372493.89, 5812194.9, 2647249.99, 726031.74, 20545728.61, 
    715457.17, 519072.81, 887038.4, 1141763.45), Habitacional = c(91108.8, 
    575485.2, 383922.33, 39546.91, 2651791.05, 1284050.8, 3085947.75, 
    1457479.11, 2922335.67, 873916.67, 8585124.87, 955206.67, 
    751732.64, 632710.19, 856063.16, 1482367.61, 309287.53, 5555929.25, 
    8324374.91, 709893.95, 297293.89, 65958.45, 7394624.99, 3599082.15, 
    794607.2, 31449547.85, 266029.41, 104924.28, 689118.33, 439479.94
    ), Veículos = c(486331.09, 1411738.47, 2068974.71, 579358.14, 
    5599813.71, 3406753.72, 5743077.32, 2954315.71, 6061609.27, 
    2664683.39, 13817515.15, 2301910.5, 3218379.71, 2900993.41, 
    1908190.37, 4421239.69, 1200083.01, 12241107.9, 12834082.84, 
    1868344.65, 1222969.11, 439364.81, 8070611.44, 9638574.2, 
    1048819.39, 54807397.34, 857305.31, 508979.96, 1450141.94, 
    2145183.6), total = c(1077506.88, 2807188.2, 3561197.24, 
    1462508.47, 11488429.81, 6759992.44, 13657219.97, 5819250.35, 
    11584463.73, 5161007.12, 28215205.56, 4685053.13, 5351962.5, 
    5673671.9, 4002617.7, 8574923.2, 2511203.26, 21265614.61, 
    32780740.83, 4164279.42, 2316706.91, 877817.15, 21277431.33, 
    15884906.34, 2569458.33, 106802673.8, 1838791.89, 1132977.05, 
    3026298.67, 3726426.99)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Meu código:

```
library(tidyverse

variacao_dados <- dados %>%
    mutate(ano = year(data)) %>%
    group_by(ano, estado) %>%
    summarise(`Empréstimo com Consignação em Folha` = sum(`Empréstimo com Consignação em Folha`),
              Habitacional = sum(Habitacional),
              `Veículos` = sum(Veículos),
              total = sum(total)) %>%
    pivot_longer(-c(ano, estado),
                 names_to = "credito",
                 values_to = "valor") %>%
    group_by(estado, credito) %>%
    mutate(variacao = valor/lag(valor, k = 1) - 1) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = "credito",
                values_from = "variacao") %>%
    select(-valor)
    filter(ano > 2009)
```

Como posso fazer para arrumar esse problema de estar repetindo os estados 4 vezes?

Comment: Dar um ungroup() antes do pivot wider? Passar id_cols = c(ano, estado) no pivot_wider pode ajudar tb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que

1. Se remover a coluna `valor` antes de reformatar para largo;
2. se passar `id_cols = c(ano, estado)` ao `pivot_wider`

o problema fica resolvido.

```
dados %>%
  mutate(ano = year(data)) %>%
  group_by(ano, estado) %>%
  summarise(`Empréstimo com Consignação em Folha` = sum(`Empréstimo com Consignação em Folha`),
            Habitacional = sum(Habitacional),
            `Veículos` = sum(Veículos),
            total = sum(total),
            .groups = "drop") %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(ano, estado),
    names_to = "credito",
    values_to = "valor"
  ) %>%
  group_by(estado, credito) %>%
  mutate(variacao = valor/lag(valor) - 1) %>% 
  select(-valor) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(ano, estado),
    names_from = credito,
    values_from = variacao
  )
```

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente, não havia notado esse detalhe.

Answer (score 2):

Se quer fazer um sumário de várias colunas, não precisa converter de comprido para longo para depois voltar para comprido; basta aplicar o mesmo cálculo para todas as colunas selecionadas.

```
colSel <- names(dados)[3:5]                    # nomes das colunas de interesse
funRes <- function(x) sum(x)/lag(sum(x)) - 1   # função para resumir os dados
```

**Com dplyr**

library(tidyverse)

```
dados %>%
  mutate(ano = year(data)) %>%
  group_by(ano, estado) %>%
  summarise_at(colSel, funRes)
```

**Com data.table**

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dados)

dados[, lapply(.SD, funRes), .(ano = year(data), estado), .SDcols = colSel]
```

Se não indicar as colunas, o padrão do `.SD` é selecionar todas menos as de agrupamento; ou seja, se vai resumir todas as colunas, não precisa usar o `.SDcols`. Veja também `?data.table::shift` para uma versão otimizada de `lag`/`lead`.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica! Não tinha pensado em nenhuma outra solução, mas será bem útil.